# Testing CustomObject marshallers in grails?

Tags: json, grails, groovy, junit, marshalling

I'm trying to create custom object marshallers in grails, and a tutorial I was following indicated that the marshaller should be setup in `BootStrap.groovy` in the `init` closure. However, when I call `myObject as JSON` in tests, the marshaller doesn't get used.

What do I need to do to use custom marshallers in tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been an issue in Grails since `1.2.4`, at least. There is an open JIRA ticket out there with no work being done.

Comment: Is this the ticket you're talking about: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6899

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to register the object marshaller any time before you use it. So to use it in a test, just add it to the setUp method.

Comment: Odd. I created a "No Class name marshaller" and registered it with priority 0, 1, and 1000, and it just doesn't seem to be being hit.

Comment: Also, this is a system-wide marshaller, so I need to have this in a more general place.